# Stop code execution if a certain value is not present in a column

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, break

I want only certain values to be filled in a column (from a list A-H) and if the value is not present in that list then the code should thrown an error and stop executing further.

```
res = APAC['colA'].isin(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])
try:
    for i in res:
        if i == False:
            print('Different response than present in the list')
except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       raise
```

In short if colA contains any other values other than A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H then thrown an error and stop code from executing further.

Using the code above, I am not able to stop code execution. Help

Comment: @Guy Giving RuntimeError even if all the values are from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise an exception instead (or in addition) to printing it. You also don't need to catch it

```
res = APAC['colA'].isin(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])
for i, val in enumerate(res):
    if not val:
        raise Exception(f'Different response than present in the list in row {i}')
```

Output in case of failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise Exception('Different response than present in the list')
Exception: Different response than present in the list in row 6
```

Comment: Thankyou so so much. Can you please guide me as to how I can "display the cell number/row number in which the Exception occurred"?